# Error in SonarQube Installation and server startup

Tags: sonarqube

I have downloaded the sonarqube and unzipped it to a folder.

As per the document ,
i have followed these steps.

1. Download the SonarQube Community Edition
2. Unzip it, let's say in C:\sonarqube or /etc/sonarqube
3. Start the SonarQube Server:

**On Windows, execute:**

"C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-xx\StartSonar.bat"

Once i execute this, i found the below error.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\Public\SIVA\SoftwareInsatallationFolder\Sonarqube\temp
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [D:\Public\SIVA\SoftwareInsatallationFolder\Sonarqube\elasticsearch]: C:\Users\Public\SIVA\SoftwareInsatallationFolder\Java\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\Public\SIVA\SoftwareInsatallationFolder\Sonarqube\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=D:\Public\SIVA\SoftwareInsatallationFolder\Sonarqube\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:32 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:32 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
jvm 1    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/D:/Public/SIVA/SoftwareInsatallationFolder/Sonarqube/lib/common/netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
jvm 1    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
jvm 1    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
jvm 1    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:36 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.12.06 14:11:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I have run the cmd as administrator , still the error exists.

help me !

Thank you !

Comment: This is not related to c# and is not programming question.

Comment: _JDK_ is installed in your machine?

Comment: Yes , JDK is Installed and environmendal variables path is also provided. @TheSprinter